# InDesing automation and DoScript() method

Tags: vb.net, adobe-indesign

I'm using Visual Basic .Net to automating InDesign, I'm trying to use a method Appllication.DoSript() to invoke my function or sub Main_Function() consist of a few steps in ONE UNDO mode, in case to make it undone by one step, so I wrote such line of code:

```
Private Sub Botton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Botton1.Click
Dim MyInDesign As Application
MyInDesign.DoScript(Main_Function, Nothing, Nothing, idUndoModes.idFastEntireScript, "Main_Function")
End Sub
```

But I always received a error message: (Invalid value for parameter 'Script' of method 'DoScript'. Expected File (String), String or JavaScript Function, but received nothing).
How I call it a right way, experts?!

Comment: Which of the parameters is being passed to `Script`?  What is `Main_Function`?

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for reply, Main_Function as I mentioned in my question is a (sub) or (function) which have some actions to made in active document, for example:
Private Sub Write_Some_Text()
Dim MyDocument As InDesign.Document = InDesign.ActiveDocument
MyDocument.Selection.Item(1).Contents = "Some Text"
End Sub

Comment: Then my best guess is that `Main_Function` is not what you should be passing as the first argument.  The error message says that it should be a string of some sort, but instead you are passing whatever the result is of calling `Main_Function` (and I don't think it would compile if it's a `Sub` either).  In any event, make sure you turn `Option Strict On` so that you get a compile error for a type mismatch vs. VB trying to muddle through and turning it into a runtime error.

Comment: Oh, thank you @Craig, but I believe that there's a way to do this, I hope that someone can give us a hint.